# Hide data-value with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following form:

```
<ul id="ui-id-1">
<li class="ui-menu-item wil-search-suggestion-item" data-value="Accommodation"><div class="ui-menu-item-wrapper"><div class="label-and-info">Accommodation</div></div></li>
<li class="ui-menu-item wil-search-suggestion-item" data-value="Activities"><div class="ui-menu-item-wrapper"><div class="label-and-info">Activities</div></div></li>
<li class="ui-menu-item wil-search-suggestion-item" data-value="Bars"><div class="ui-menu-item-wrapper"><div class="label-and-info">Bars</div></div></li>
<li class="ui-menu-item wil-search-suggestion-item" data-value="Day Clubs"><div class="ui-menu-item-wrapper"><div class="label-and-info">Day Clubs</div></div></li>
<li class="ui-menu-item wil-search-suggestion-item" data-value="Events"><div class="ui-menu-item-wrapper"><div class="label-and-info">Events</div></div></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to be able to hide the Events listing from it. This is from a Wordpress theme which I am unable to edit.

Is there a CSS hack I can use at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
ul li:last-child {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

This takes the last child of the list within the un-ordered list, and hides it. (since 'events' is the last of the list)